# how to change effectively the In clause in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, where-clause

we have a employee_master table and a Report_Filter Table, the Report_Filter contains different typs of filter the user enters for eg. status, employee code,  nationaality etc. and this report_filter contains the user Information also. The table structure is like this Report_Filter(  User_Id, Report_TYpe, Report_Code ) all are character fields.  based on the users input the table will have values like

```
( 'User_1', 'STATUS', '01' ) 
( 'user_1', 'STATUS', '02'  ) 
( 'User_1', 'EMP_CODE', 'ABC' ) 
( 'User_1', 'NATIONALITY', 'ALL' ) -- All means he want to see all the nationalities
```

now currently we are writing the query like this

```
Select Emp_code, Emp_Name, status, nationlity 

From  Empolyee_Master m
Where 

('All' in ( select report_code from Report_Filter where user_id = @user_id and report_type='STATUS') or m.STATUS in ( select report_code from Report_Filter where user_id = @user_id and report_type='STATUS') )    and  

or m.CATEGORY in ( select report_code from Report_Filter where user_id = @user_id and report_type='NATIONALITY') )               and  

or m.emp_code in ( select report_code from Report_Filter where user_id = @user_id and report_type='EMP_CODE') )
```

there are other conditions also we are using, the problem is its take too much time because of the In clauses. how can we effectively change this code for improving performance

we are using MSSQL 2014

Comment: That is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of retrieving all values and then seeing if your value is part of it, you should filter by your value. Try if this helps (just one example):

*replace*

```
WHERE 'ALL' in (
    select report_code from Report_Filter
    where user_id = @user_id and report_type='STATUS'
)
```

*with*

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    select 1 from Report_Filter
    where user_id = @user_id and report_type='STATUS'
    and   report_code = 'ALL'
)
```

Now it would also help to include column `report_code` in an INDEX (you are using INDEXes, I hope?)

---

**Update** - to skip filtering in case of 'ALL', that can be done like this:

```
DECLARE @statusFilter VARCHAR(20) = ...  -- 'ALL' or other value

SELECT ...
WHERE @statusFilter = 'ALL'
OR EXISTS (
    select 1 from Report_Filter
    where user_id = @user_id and report_type='STATUS'
    and   report_code = @statusFilter
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Replay.

Comment: if the user didnt selected any records we are pushing only 1 record with a value as 'All' . so there is no multiple records in that type only one record will be there

Comment: If the value is all then no checking is requried against the main table

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the filtering in advance:

(For your next question: Such a *mockup* should be done by you)

```
DECLARE @ReportFilter TABLE([user_id] VARCHAR(100),report_type VARCHAR(100),report_code VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @ReportFilter VALUES
 ( 'User_1', 'STATUS', '01' ) 
,( 'user_1', 'STATUS', '02'  ) 
,( 'User_1', 'EMP_CODE', 'ABC' ) 
,( 'User_1', 'NATIONALITY', 'ALL' );

DECLARE @Employee_Master TABLE(Emp_Code VARCHAR(100),Emp_Name VARCHAR(100), [status] VARCHAR(100), nationality VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Employee_Master VALUES
 ('ABC','test1','01','USA')
,('DEF','test2','99','GB')
,('ABC','test3','02','DE')
,('XYZ','test4','01','FRA');
```

--This is part of your query

```
DECLARE @user_id VARCHAR(100)='User_1';

WITH filterSTATUS AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @ReportFilter WHERE [user_id]=@user_id AND report_type='STATUS'
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ReportFilter WHERE [user_id]=@user_id AND report_type='STATUS' AND report_code='ALL')
)
,
filterEMPCODE AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @ReportFilter WHERE [user_id]=@user_id AND report_type='EMP_CODE'
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ReportFilter WHERE [user_id]=@user_id AND report_type='EMP_CODE' AND report_code='ALL')
)
,filterNATIONALITY AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @ReportFilter WHERE [user_id]=@user_id AND report_type='NATIONALITY'
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ReportFilter WHERE [user_id]=@user_id AND report_type='NATIONALITY' AND report_code='ALL')
)
SELECT * 
FROM @Employee_Master AS em
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filterSTATUS)=0 OR em.[status] IN (SELECT x.report_code FROM filterSTATUS AS x)
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filterEMPCODE)=0 OR em.Emp_Code IN (SELECT x.report_code FROM filterEMPCODE AS x)
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filterNATIONALITY)=0 OR em.nationality IN (SELECT x.report_code FROM filterNATIONALITY AS x);
```

For the give set this returns

```
Emp_Code    Emp_Name    status  nationality
ABC         test1       01      USA
ABC         test3       02      DE
```